# Free mercurial repo hosting that supports pull using web browser

Tags: mercurial, repository, hosting

I'm looking for the ideal *free* mercurial hosting site. Ideally it should support

- Public and private repos.
- Allows Non Open Source projects.
- The ability for mercurial users, in some cases, to anonymously access the repo without requiring a login
- The ideal would be if people who did not even have Mercurial *installed* could use a web browser to pull the code as I'm not sure I can mandate the installation of Mercurial on all the users machines.

I have begun my search with Assembla and am working my way through this list, will probably try BitBucket next. So are some or all of the above possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "web pull"? You need hg installed to pull or do anything with a repository. Or do you mean downloading a tarball of the state of the repository (at a given revision)?

Comment: @Chris Morgan: I suppose he meant accepting pull requests via web interface

Comment: I mean that people can get the code in one operation with just a web browser. Who voted this down and why?

Comment: @ScrollerBlaster: I guess people would downvote this because it doesn't seem very well researched: searching Google for "free mercurial hosting site" brings you to Bitbucket which is the biggest such site. They support all the features you ask for.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I feel the votes are unfair in this case. I knew of BitBucket as I had already done the research. However the features I am looking for are not immediately in evidence in these situations until you have done a proof of concept and there are a lot of repos to try out. Didn't think there'd be any harm in asking those who had already been there as usually free hosting will not hit all your requirements. I've got a suggestion below, now comes the proof of concept.

Comment: @ScrollerBlaster: okay, the question just didn't felt very well researched to me — "everybody" knows that Bitbucket is the largest and most featureful free Mercurial hosting site. But apparently you wasn't included in "everybody" :-) Since you Googled first, I've now given the question a +1. Good luck with it!

Comment: Thanks, my profile page now looks more respectable!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BitBucket fits to all your requirements.

**Edit - update**: Not anymore.  It will offer Mercurial hosting until 2020-05-31, before going Git-only.

Comment: Pretty impressed with this after doing my proof of concept. Anonymous Mercural pull or easy "get source" as a zip file for web browser users who don't have Mercurial. I hope it's OK that my private repo is not open source in the free plan?

Comment: @ScrollerBlaster: yep. The only limitations is team members amount - and you can store whatever you want there

Comment: Cool. It can be a bit slow at times, but I'll cope!